# How to Show/Hide textfield based on dropdown list in J2ME?

Tags: drop-down-menu, java-me

I am having a dropdown list in my J2ME form, Now i want to show one textfield when select the particular value of dropdown list, and the same time when i choose any other value of dropdown list that text field should hide.

How to do this in J2ME?

Answer (score 0):

You can set ItemStateListener for the form that contains the dropdown list, and whenever dropdown selection changes, listener's itemStateChanged method is called and you can append/insert the textfield to the form or delete it from it, according to dropdown selected value.